# How would you repair a clogged windshield wiper sprayer?

Tags: honda, accord, windshield-wipers, windshield-washer

I have a 2000 Honda Accord. When I trigger the windshield wiper fluid onto the front windshield, the right sprayer works fine but the left one seems clogged and it sprays very minimally. Because of this, I cannot clean my windshield fully and it usually streaks. Is there any way to repair this?

Answer (score 6):

**High Pressure Air**

I would disconnect the hose from that sprayer from the motor that gives it the pressure to spray.

I would go where there is high pressure air.  In my case that would be my shop.

I would have an air gun with a rubber tip.

I would take that air gun with a rubber tip and push it tightly against the sprayer nozzle and use the high pressure air to blow the offending particle backwards through it's windshield wiper fluid delivery hose.

Re-attach hose to wiper fluid delivery pump and spray away.

Here's a photo of the air pressure blow gun with a rubber tip.

[image]

Comment: If that does not work, replace the nozzle, they are cheap at Honda.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to repair these jets (and re-align them) by using a dress pin pushed down the nozzle.  Typically either dirt or polish (depending on how you maintain your car) accumulates at the exit point of the nozzle and a pin is enough to clear it.

Comment: If the blockage at the nozzle and you've got a [Bowles Fluidic nozzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVPwqyvY1aA), the push pin method won't work.  You will want to use compressed air.  Not sure if Honda uses those but most Detroit based cars certainly do.

Comment: 2000 Honda Accord just uses "normal" jet type nozzles.

Answer (score 1):

Many manufacturers will recommend insertion of a pin to unclog a windshield sprayer.

It doesn't always work but is definitely worth trying before buying.